# Filter observable until mapped observable finishes

Tags: rxjs

What I have is this:

```
var click = fromEvent(button, 'click');

var animation = from([]).pipe(
    concat(
        animateDiv(300, 600),
        animateDiv(-300, 600),
        animateDiv( 300, 300),
        animateDiv(-300, 300)
    ));

click.pipe(
    flatMap(() => animation),
).subscribe();
```

Each animateDiv() returns an Observable which completes once the animation is finished. With "concat()" I chain them together.

So now I would like to not start another animation on "click" while the other animation chain is still running...

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Try `exaustMap` or `concatMap` in lieu of `flatMap`. The first will ignore all the click events emitted untill the running animation finished. The latter will not *loose* any click, but will concatenate all animations one after the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: [audit](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-audit)

```
var animation = concat(
    animateDiv(300, 600),
    animateDiv(-300, 600),
    animateDiv(300, 300),
    animateDiv(-300, 400),
);

click.pipe(
    audit(() => animation)
).subscribe();
```